# Django order by pviot table column

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I want to order tasks within a bucket based on the 'order' column in the 'bucket_task' table. Tasks and buckets have a many-to-many relationship. How can I achieve this?

My models:

```py
class Bucket(AbstractModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='buckets', on_delete=models.deletion.DO_NOTHING)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=191, blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)



class Task(AbstractModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tasks', on_delete=models.deletion.DO_NOTHING)
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=191, blank=True)


class BucketTask(AbstractModel):
    bucket = models.ForeignKey(Bucket, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

My view:

```py
class BucketsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = BucketSerializer
    model = Bucket

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.model.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user,
            deleted_on__isnull=True
        ).prefetch_related(
            'tasks'
        ).select_related('user').order_by('order')
        return queryset
```

My Serializer:

```py
class BucketSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bucket
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ['unique_id', 'tasks']
        extra_kwargs = {"user": {"required": False}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify this in a [**`Prefetch`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


class BucketsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = BucketSerializer
    model = Bucket

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, deleted_on=None)
            .prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('tasks', Task.objects.order_by('buckettask__order'))
            )
            .select_related('user')
            .order_by('order')
        )
```

---

> **Note**: Using [**`deleted_on__isnull=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#std-fieldlookup-isnull) can be shortened to `deleted_on=None`, since Django inspects if the value is `None`, and if that is the case, [**`__exact`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#std-fieldlookup-exact) acts as `isnull=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not specified a `related_name` argument to the `bucket` FK field on `BucketTask` model, you can access the 'BucketTask`table from the`Bucket`table by using`buckettask_set`.

So, you can do:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, deleted_on__isnull=True).prefetch_related('tasks'
 ).select_related('user').order_by('buckettask_set__order')
    return queryset
```

Comment: This will only order the `Bucket`s, and also deduplicate these, so the same `Bucket` will be repeated that many times as there are `Task`s for that `Bucket`, so this will not order the `Task`s *per* `Bucket`, but create a `Bucket` in the result *per* *related* `Task`.